# Where to format/place the "{" in C?

Tags: c, coding-style

Can anyone explain me please why here:

```
void
st_clear(st_table *table)
{ //1 a new line
    register st_table_entry *ptr, *next;
    st_index_t i;

    if (table->entries_packed) { //2 the same line
        table->num_entries = 0;
        table->real_entries = 0;
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < table->num_bins; i++) {
      ptr = table->bins[i];
      table->bins[i] = 0;
      while (ptr != 0) {
        next = ptr->next;
        st_free_entry(ptr);
        ptr = next;
      }
    }
    table->num_entries = 0;
    table->head = 0;
    table->tail = 0;
}
```

in one case they left `{` of the same line, whereas in another put to the new line?

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1b5acebef2d447a3dbed6cf5e146fda74b81f10d/st.c

I know in C there's no a definite naming convention like in most other languages, yet `{` within one project **always** has to be put **either** on the new line or left on the same line.

Comment: This is completely stylistic.

Comment: @T.C., I know. But there must consistency.

Comment: "within one project always has to be but either on the new line or left on the same line" -- no it doesn't.  The compiler doesn't care.  Humans might, but apparently they don't.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, no one has said a compiler cared.

Comment: "always" sounds like a requirement. This is [a pretty common bracing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) - function braces on new lines, others on the same line.

Comment: Most IDEs just format it the first way. And whitespaces and `\n` don't matter in C

Comment: There are a number of "common archetypes" of [C (and derivative) Indent Styles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), but there is no One C[orrect] Way. Eg. K&R, Allman, Whitesmith, GNU, BSD, Banner, etc. Hopefully a particular project has style/guideline rules which are then followed within the applicable scope but this is not required. As such this question leads to entirely opinionated (or rebuttal) responses.

Comment: @user2864740, I have discovered the one correct way but this comment box is too small to contain my proof :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm not much a theoretician, but `#define DO {` - now that is all practicality! :D

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing in the C standard itself that mandates placement of tokens, provided they're in the right order. In fact:

```
i

     = j

++;
```

is perfectly okay, syntax wise, despite it being seriously ugly formatting for:

```
i = j++;
```

Having said that, you should stick to your *guidelines* as much as possible. In this case, we don't actually know what the guidelines *are.*

It's entirely possible that the guidelines state different brace placement for functions and non-functions.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, this is completely valid, and is indeed part of many common indentation-styles, e.g. K&R-style (Wikipedia has a [summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Styles) of some popular styles).

Why this is done in this case, is hard to answer without the coding-style guidelines (with some rationale) being followed for this code, but an advantage is, that there is a function definition if and only if there’s a line matching `^[{]`, so they can be found easily. (Functions do not nest in standard C, so the `{` is always at the first column, and there (apparently) aren’t any other constructs where a `{` is at the first column in this coding style convention.)

As mentioned in the Wikipedia article linked above, old-style definitions may have been another (though historic) reason for this convention to become popular.

The `{` introducing a function definition is different from other braces at the beginning of a compound statement, in that it is required (function bodies are the only case where a compound statement cannot be replaced by some other statement, `int foo(void) return 5;`, for example, is invalid). This may somewhat legitimate the inconsistency (if you consider it such) with the placement of other braces in different circumstances.